# How to resolve class cast exception when two same classes having same name, package and content?

Tags: java, exception, classcastexception

I am having same class with everything including package name and content same. still getting class cast exception while accessing two web application hosted on same tomcat. How to resolve the same ?

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/CourtForms] threw exception
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.courts.sec.UserProfile cannot be cast to com.ibm.courts.sec.UserProfile
        at web.clerk.courtforms.servlet.FilterAuthentication.doFilter(FilterAuthentication.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1629)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Don't post images of errors, and post the full stack trace please. As text.

Comment: Based on the information provided, there is no reason to believe or disbelieve your diagnosis.

Comment: added stack trace and updated description. Please help

Comment: How can I help? Exactly?

Comment: How to resolve above exception ? I am having same class with everything including package name and content same. still getting class cast exception while accessing two web application hosted on same tomcat. How to resolve the same ?

Answer (score 3):

Usually, having two classes with the same package and name is not a problem since the class loader will always just pick one (i.e. the first in the classpath).

It is more likely that your classes were loaded by different classloaders. In Java, classes loaded by different classloaders are not compatible and assigning them will result in a `ClassCastException`. This is by design.

From your stack trace it looks that you are using Tomcat; in many cases this is caused by having a library in both shared libs as well as deployed with web application. Again, this is not because of a duplicate class but because of `ClassLoader` design. If this is the case, either remove this library from shared libs or from `.war` you are deploying.

Comment: ok. How can I make my applications use same class loaders ? I am using tomcat 8.5. Both web application are deployed on same tomcat.

Comment: Issue has been resolved by adding <Loader delegate="true"/> in context.xml of tomcat.

Comment: @Rahul Be aware that this is not the proper solution, but merely a workaround to avoid the problem. The problem is still there waiting for you.

Comment: Then how to resolve it ? Because I am not using war file to run application in tomcat. I am using context path in server.xml to run application and running two different project in same tomcat. I am facing UserProfile class and this class present in both project and I am getting userProfile data from one project and storing in another project's userProfile.

Comment: As I said, you have two choices: either (a) give each project a copy of this library and remove it from shared classes, or (b) move this library to shared classes and remove it from both projects. Option (a) is usually safer as it prevents one application to corrupt the other, but it will increase your memory footprint.